# Unsigned binary subtraction when numbers are too large to form two's complement

Tags: binary, unsigned, subtraction

I am in computer architecture and my prof. hasn't been able to give a satisfactory answer.

Assuming we have a 32-bit processor, if we have two unsigned integers *x* and *y*, both of which are greater than 2<sup>31</sup> (so that they are too large to be converted properly to two's complement form) how do we perform subtraction?

If the subtrahend was a constant I can see how the compiler could compensate for this in static analysis.  But how do we deal with this possibility at runtime, especially in a statically-compiled language like C?  Does this just throw an overflow error or do some architectures `subu` support special operations?

Everything I find for MIPS says that it just performs two's complement subtraction, but that shouldn't work in this case, should it?

Answer (score 1):

The situation you pose is not a problem.  Specific example:

```
  0xFFFFFFFF -  0xFFFF0000
= 0xFFFFFFFF + -0xFFFF0000
= 0xFFFFFFFF +  0x00010000
= 0x0000FFFF
```

Comment: Somehow I messed up my subtraction on paper here, as I got different results. But this was what I thought as well. +1.